# wordpress: set custom class for first post then next 2 post and the rest differently

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a way to modify this code to get the first styled differently, then the next 2 post styled differently while the rest of the post will be styled differently too.

```
<?php
$queryObject = new  Wp_Query( array(
    'showposts' => 5,
    'post_type' => array('post'),
    'category_name' => videos,
    'orderby' => 1,
    ));

// The Loop
if ( $queryObject->have_posts() ) :
    $i = 0;
    while ( $queryObject->have_posts() ) :
        $queryObject->the_post();
        if ( $i == 0 ) : ?>
            <div class="first-post">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ), wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('sidethumbs'); ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif;
        if ( $i != 0 ) : ?>
            <div class="secondary-post">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
        </div>
        <?php $i++;
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

I have tried but this is what I have so far. Please help.

Comment: You can use a switch case, and determaine a class name.

Comment: or just to modify your entire output

Comment: Thanks but can you give a code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a switch case could look like this - This way you can specify how the first, second and rest should look like - But you could also just use `if(){} elseif(){} else{}`

```
<?php
$queryObject = new  Wp_Query( array(
'showposts' => 5,
'post_type' => array('post'),
'category_name' => videos,
'orderby' => 1,
));

// The Loop
if ( $queryObject->have_posts() ) :
$i = 0;
while ( $queryObject->have_posts() ) :
    $queryObject->the_post();
    $postClass = "";
    switch ($i) {
        case 0:
            $postClass = "firstpost";?>
            <div class="<?php echo $postClass;?>">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ), wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('sidethumbs'); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php break;
        case 1:
            $postClass = "secondpost";
            //More of the same stuff.
        break;
        default:
           $postClass = "restOfPosts";
           //How the rest of the posts should look like
        break;
    }
$i++;
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. this looks good but shows only one post. I wanted something that will show first post floated to the left, then 2n and 3rd post in the center while the remaining 4, 5, 6 etc floats to the right. This looks like showing a single loop in 3 columns with first on the left 2nd and 3rd in the center and the rest of the post on the right. Thanks for your time but you could help me more to get this correctly.

Comment: This only shows the first post, because the second and rest post is not done :) Basically, do the same for case 1 and default. `case 0:` means `do this for the first case` - `case 1: ` is `do this for the second case` and the default is `if it is not the first or second case, then do this`

Comment: Thanks bro... because I dont understand how to do this I have decided to use 'offset' and use the same loop on every column. It works for me and i understand it better. Maybe with time I will learn how to implement your method. Thanks. for Clarity see what I wanted to achieve here [link](https://tophits.ng/news/)